# $\phi:\mathcal F\rightarrow \mathcal G$ is an isomorphism if there is an open cover on which $\phi(U)$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ be sheaves of abelian groups over a topological space $X$ and let $\phi : \mathcal F\rightarrow \mathcal G$ be a morphism of sheaves.

**If $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ is an open cover of $X$ such that $\phi(U_{\alpha}):\mathcal F(U_{\alpha})\rightarrow\mathcal G(U_{\alpha})$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups for every $\alpha$ then is it true that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of sheaves?**

While trying to prove this  I had to assume that for an open set $U\subseteq X$ the map $\phi(U_{\alpha}\cap U)$ is an isomorphism. However I can't show this unless the restriction map $\mathcal G(U_{\alpha})\rightarrow\mathcal G(U_{\alpha}\cap U)$ is surjective. So is there another way to prove this or is it false? Can someone give me a counter example?

Thank you.

Comment: You need the much stronger assumption that $\phi|_{U_\alpha}$ is an isomorphism of _sheaves_ for each $\alpha$.

Comment: @Slade. Oh yes I can see how to prove it then. Thank you.

Comment: One could perhaps also try to prove the statement if the $U_\alpha$ form a base for the topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. Let $X$ be any topological space, equipped with a nonzero sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ that has no global sections except $0$ (such spaces and sheaves exist). Consider the trivial $1$-element cover of $X$, and let $\phi$ be the $0$-morphism $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}$. Clearly, the morphism $\phi$ induces an isormorphism $\phi(X):\mathcal{F}(X)\to\mathcal{F}(X)$, but $\phi$ is not an isomorphism of sheaves.

An example of such a sheaf is the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, this is the sheaf of sections of the 'tautological' line bundle, which is a vector bundle whose fiber over a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ corresponding to a line $\ell\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ is the line $\ell$ itself. (The specifics of the proof here depend a bit on what category you're working in, algebraic, analytic, topological...).

Comment: Do you have an example of such a sheaf?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is an example. It has no non-zero global sections.

Comment: @npna It seems we were thinking of the same example at the same time! There must be a more elementary topological example that fits the very general framework better...

Comment: @JakobOesinghaus Any topological space that does not have the trivial topology has such a sheaf: take a nonempty open $U\subsetneq X$, take the constant sheaf $A$ on $U$ (for some nonzero abelian group $A$), and extend by zero, i.e. $\mathcal{F}(V)=0$ if $V\not\subset U$.